# is there a simple way to replace a style by another in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

i would like to change all the occurrence `style="width: 1px;"` by `style="width: 41px;"` in *fullcalendar agendaWeek* after it render,
 for that i used `eventAfterRender`
 and my code is

```
    eventAfterRender: function(event, $el, view) {
                        if( 'agendaWeek' === view.name ) {
                            var r = new RegExp(style="width: 1px;", "g");
                            var txtWith = 'style="width: 41px;"';

                            $el.find(".fc-body").val().replace(r, 
                            txtWith).
                            replace(/\</g, "&lt;").replace(/\>/g, 
                           "&gt;").replace(/\&/g, "&amp;");
        }
```

Comment: Can you use CSS classes instead of inline styling?

Comment: the inline styling is used by fullcalendar, i want to replace the css after it render, it is the only way i found to fix, it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to change the inline style attribute, I would assign a CSS class which overrides the inline styling.

```
$el.addClass('wideCell');
```

The class `.wideCell` would be something like this:

```
.wideCell {
    width: 41px !important;
}
```

If you absolutely want to go with the replacement strategy, I would advise to use the following regex:

```js
 function replaceInlineWidth(element) {
    // When the element has no style attribute, skip it.
    if (!element.hasAttribute('style')) {
      return;
    }
    
    // Get the style attribute from the element
    var inlineStyle = element.getAttribute('style'), 
        regex = /width\s?:\s?\d+px(?:;|$)/g;
        
    // Replace the inline width declaration with 41px
    inlineStyle = inlineStyle.replace(regex, 'width: 41px;');
    // Set the modified style attribute back on the element.
    element.setAttribute('style', inlineStyle);
 }
 
 // Create a test element.
 var 
    element = document.createElement('div');
    
 // Give the test element some inline style.
 element.setAttribute('style', 'background-color: #000; width: 1px; margin: 1em;');
 // Run the replacement method.
 replaceInlineWidth(element);
 // Log the inline style, the width should be 41px.
 console.log(element.getAttribute('style'));
```

It will match things like `width:1px`, `width :1px`, and `width: 1px`. It also matches `width: 30px`. It will be a bit more resilient. If you really only want to replace `width: 1px` change the regex to `width\s?:\s?1px(?:;|$)`.

Comment: in the view i have many tag like this      `<td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 1px;">` , all of them have  a class **fc-axis**, what i did is `$el.find(".fc-axis").addClass('wideCell');` but nothing happen

Comment: You've added the `wideCell` class in your stylesheet?

Comment: for sure, the HACK that i found is to go to **fullcalendar.js** than add *wideCell* class after "fc-axis", it work but i do not like it, in rendering `style="width: 1px;"` still exist but  like *wideCell* is important it override it

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. Is it working but you're not happy with the solution or it isn't working?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it does work, but the solution is not pretty, also i'm disappointed that i didn't find a way to replace the style by another, a find and replace thing, i must be really bad in JS, thanks for the help,

Comment: I've updated my answer with a method to replace the inline styling.

Comment: the code that finally worked for me, is this, ```eventAfterRender: function(event, $el, view) {
                if( 'agendaWeek' === view.name ) {
                    var x = $(view.el[0]).find(".fc-axis");
                    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                        replaceInlineWidth(x[i]);
                    }

                }
            }```, thanks to @Thijs

Answer (score 0):

to change  *fc-axis* style,

### First solution,

@Thijs idea

1. add to your css file,

   .wideCell {
       width: 41px !important;
   }
2. go to **fullcalendar.js** and add `wideCell` to any class that contain `fc-axis`, EXP

   `'<td class="fc-axis fc-time '`

become

`'<td class="fc-axis fc-time wideCell '`

without it i would have
[fullcalendar weekview not showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khYcF.png)

but it should be like this  [fullcalendar weekview showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsVmx.png)

### Second solution

open **fullcalendar.js** and change

`var maxInnerWidth = 0;` to `var maxInnerWidth = 40;\\40 or what ever feet your need`,

Comment: The second solution will certainly work but it is error prone. When a new version of fullcalendar is released you have to remember to modify it again to suite your needs.